# Using the Yelp api in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dictionary, yelp

I'm still new to programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to use the Yelp api in a new app I'm making. I integrated the api using the example project provided by Yelp here: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api (v2/objective c). My question is how do I access the information that the sample program logs out. It saves it in an NSDictionary but I can't figure out how to access the info so I can for example display the business's phone number in a label in one of my view controllers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would access the `keys` and `objects` just as you would any other `NSDictionary`, for example in `YPAPISample.m`:

```
- (void)queryTopBusinessInfoForTerm:
          (NSString *)term location:
          (NSString *)location completionHandler:
          (void (^)(NSDictionary *topBusinessJSON, NSError *error))
          completionHandler {
  ...

  NSString *phoneNumber = [firstBusiness objectForKey:@"display_phone"];
  NSLog(@"PHONE NUMBER: %@",phoneNumber);
```

**Output**:

> PHONE NUMBER: +1-415-777-1413